# Proof verification: A differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ is a contraction if $||f'||_{sup} = r < 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Definition of contraction:** A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is called a *contraction* of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there exists a constant $r\in[0,1)$ such that for all $x$ and $x'$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we have

$$|f(x)-f(x')| \leq r|x-x'|.$$

> *Proof:* The function $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,  $f'(x)$ exists and we will denote it as
>   $r$. We are given that $|r|<1$ since $||f'||_{sup} < 1$. Then,
>
> $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=r$$  $$f(x+h)-f(x)=rh$$
>
> Letting $x' = x+h$, we get
>
> $$f(x')-f(x)=r(x-x')$$ $$\implies |f(x')-f(x)|=r|(x-x')|$$
>
> and $f$ must be a contraction of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the reasoning from the first to the second line?

Comment: Did you mean to type $\|f'\|_{sup}$ in the second line?

Comment: What about using the mean value theorem and a simple estimate?

Comment: @rubik Yes, I edited it now.

Comment: @ detnvvp do you mean from first equation to second equation or first sentence to the second sentence?

Comment: @ThePuix I haven't learned mean value theorem and a simple estimate yet. Should I use it to prove this instead of only using the definition of differential?

Comment: Well, if the question doesn't specifically disallows its use, I suggest you look it up. The wording 'simple estimate' didn't mean anything more specific than what is given in the inequality for the derivative.